# How can I determine if Oracle is installed on Microsoft Windows or Unix using SQL?

Tags: oracle

Is there a view in which I can check it? I need to create a script using the `SUBSTR` function by `/` (Linux) or `\` (Windows).

```
SUBSTR('anything', 1, INSTR('anything', '/', 1, 1)) -- Linux

SUBSTR('anything', 1, INSTR('anything', '\\', 1, 1)) -- Windows
```

Comment: Where is that path used? Are you sure it wouldn't be more relevant to determine the client's environment rather than the server's?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
SQL> select platform_name from v$database;

PLATFORM_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Linux x86 64-bit
```

To answer your original problem:

```
SQL> select sys_context('userenv', 'platform_slash') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','PLATFORM_SLASH')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/
```

[SYS_CONTEXT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SYS_CONTEXT.html)

> PLATFORM_SLASH
>
> The slash character that is used as the file path delimiter for your
> platform.

Comment: Where is the prompt from? [SQL Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Plus)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes.